# How Do I Get Out of Boot Loop on iPhone 4?

Tags: iphone, jailbreak

I dropped my iPhone (jailbroken, running on IOS 7.0.6), and it went blank - it has this habit of being switched off own its on when it's dropped. I tried holding the sleep/power button, but it's not showing me the Apple logo (usually, it will show me the logo when I pressed the button). I can't do the DFU or Recovery Mode as my home button is kind of not working, unless I press it with the right amount of force.

I tried plugging in to my computer, and nothing is detected (the cable is working just fine). However, my phone will go into the endless boot loop when I plugged into the socket/charger. While it's booting, I tried holding the volume (+), but it never worked.

So, how do I get out of this boot loop with 'kind of not working' home button? I'm avoiding the idea of buying a new phone, but if it's my last resort, I guess I have no choice.

Answer (score 1):

My advice would be to fix your home button (here's an excellent guide from ifixit if you want to fix it yourself: https://www.ifixit.com/Guide/iPhone+4+Home+Button+Replacement/3144) and then put it into DFU mode. If your home button is dodgy, fixing it will greatly enhance your chances of getting into DFU mode in order to restore it within iTunes.

There are tools that exist to get your device into DFU mode with a broken home button however these are unlikely to succeed if iTunes isn't detecting anything and your device is bootlooping.